# Microsoft excel 2016 - Need to total the number of cells within a date range

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I just need to total amount of cells in a date range

```
25/03/2019
25/03/2019
28/02/2019
28/02/2019
28/02/2019
18/03/2019
26/03/2019
27/03/2019
27/03/2019
27/03/2019
27/03/2019
27/03/2019
27/03/2019
27/03/2019
27/03/2019
25/03/2019
28/01/2019
03/04/2019
03/04/2019
03/04/2019
03/04/2019
```

How many in March for example?

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Your question isn't quite clear.  "Total" typically means to sum values.  I'm guessing that what you need is either to **count** the number of rows that meet your criteria (like being between two dates), or select rows based on dates in that column being between specified start and end points, and sum values in another column based on that selection.  There's actually a third possibility, but probably not what you want.  Dates are stored as numbers, so theoretically, you could want to sum those internal numbers for the qualifying dates.  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

I would create and extra column next to the date column that will retrieve the month from the date, I would then use a count if on the new column to see how many times the required date appears

see below

https://res.cloudinary.com/dlkdmqcop/image/upload/v1554716969/excel_countif_sawugz.png

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list is in A1, then in B1 enter 1/3/2019 and in C1 enter the formula;

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$21,">="&B1,$A$1:$A$21,"<="&EOMONTH(B1,0))
```

If you want a range rather than a full month enter the range start date in B1 and the range end date in B2 and use this formula;

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$21,">="&B1,$A$1:$A$21,"<="&B2)
```